# Attribution muddled by Financing Partner

Tags: google-analytics, attribution

In Google Analytics, under Conversion > Attribution > Attribution Model Comparison Tool, I am running into an attribution problem. Our e-commerce company has partnered with a financing company that allows visitors to purchase our product by financing with our partner. This requires our user to click a link that takes them from our purchase page, to our partner's page. After getting approved for financing, they are redirected to our page, and the purchase is completed. 
This causes a problem in Google Analytics. To Google Analytics, it looks like our partner page is the referring media source, so many of our purchases show up under the source/medium of our financing partner. In reality, these people originally came from some other media source like Facebook, instagram or google.

Is there a way to bypass the traffic from this specific source/medium (our financing partner) so that I can see where these purchases originated from?

Comment: Is this not solved by adding your partner to the referral exclusion list (in the property settings) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this scenario, you'd probably want to add the partner domain to the Referral Exclusion List. https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2795830

Note, there is something more sinister happening as well to your session counts. As the user returns with a new referrer,  meaning the source/medium/campaign changed during a session,  the previous sessions closes out and a new session is created. So this is ruining your session based metrics like pages/visit, time on site, etc... https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2731565

Comment: Pat, do you think that my Time Lag and Path Length data could be artificially affected by my current setup? If so, would "Referral exclusion" fix this?

Comment: Any metric that uses session scoped aggregation would be negatively impacted by this. I think some impact the "directionality" of the analysis more than others. Time lag and path length are both important,  so fixing issues in measurement is important to keep confidence high!